# I never get notified when device rotation is in .PortraitUpsideDown

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I have the following method inside my only `ViewController`.

```
override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    println("willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation")
    super.willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation, duration: duration)

    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
    case .Portrait: println(".Portrait")
    case .PortraitUpsideDown: println(".PortraitUpsideDown")
    case .LandscapeRight: println(".LandscapeRight")
    case .LandscapeLeft: println(".LandscapeLeft")
    case .Unknown: println(".Unknown")
    }
}
```

And I enabled all possible orientations in the project settings

[image: Settings]

But even if I rotate 360 in the simulator (same goes for my iPhone), I never get ".PortraitUpsideDown" printed in the console. Why? It almost seems, like Apple doesn't allow this rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically return portrait upside down in `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` in your base `UIViewController`

The method implementation should look like so.

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: OK, this totally lost me. That method returns an `Int`, but the orientations are defined as `enums`. How do I reconcile the two?

Comment: @MorganWilde, `return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)` from `supportedInterfaceOrientations`

Comment: Thanks @vacawama you provided 50% of the answer :)